# Twisted web server stops responding to http requests

Tags: python, twisted

```
import cx_Oracle
import json
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site, NOT_DONE_YET
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

salesVolumeResult = []
unscheduledResult = []

class SalesVolume(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

def render_GET(self, request):
    return salesVolumeResult

class Unscheduled(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
    return unscheduledResult

class GetResultsFromDB():
    def __init__(self):    
    print '__init__'
    self.myDsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('ipaddress',1521,'SID')
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('cx_Oracle', user='uname', password     ='password', dsn= self.myDsn)

    def _getResults(self, txn, query):
        print '_getResults'
        txn.execute(query)
        return txn.fetchall()


    def printResults(self, results, query_type):
        print 'printResults'

        #here is the logic to get result
        if query_type == 'sales':
            global salesVolumeResult
            salesVolumeResult = json.dumps(mastervalue)
        elif query_type == 'unscheduled':
             global unscheduledResult
             unscheduledResult = json.dumps(mastervalue)
        else:
             print 'Unknown query type'

    def printError(self, error):
        print error.getErrorMessage()
        self.dbpool.close

    def closeDBCallback(self, results):
        print 'closeDBCallback'
        print 'successful'
        self.dbpool.close

    def queryUnscheduledResults(self, result):
        print 'queryUnscheduledResults'
        query_unscheduled = "select query which runs for 10 seconds"
        (self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._getResults, query_unscheduled).addCallback(
            self.printResults, "unscheduled").addErrback(self.printError)).addCallbacks(self.closeDBCallback).addErrback(self.printError)


    def querySalesResult(self):
        print 'querySalesResult'

        query_salesVolume = "select ..."
        (self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._getResults, query_salesVolume).addCallback(
            self.printResults, "sales").addErrback(self.printError)).addCallbacks(self.queryUnscheduledResults).addErrback(self.printError)

    def initiateDBIteration(self):
        print 'initiateDBIteration'
        i = task.LoopingCall(self.querySalesResult)
        i.start(300.0).addCallbacks(self.initiateDBIteration, self.printError)

def main():
    GetResultsFromDB().initiateDBIteration()
    root = Resource()
    root.putChild("salesvolume", SalesVolume())
    root.putChild("unscheduled", Unscheduled())
    factory = Site(root)
    reactor.listenTCP(8888, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A gist on this program. I have a task which looks every 5 min, query's the oracle database, returns result and updates the value(sales volume).Then again, via a callback fire another query, and update the second value (unscheduled).

There is a web Resource, which listens at port 8888. So when I "get" requests "/salesvolume"  and "/unscheduled" and return respective strings.

I have another Node.js server, which includes socket, I query via restify api to "example.com/salesvolume" and return string provided by the above python code. Problem is this twisted server stops responding after like one hour. What is the problem with the code.

Comment: Try enabling logging so you can see if there are errors or other useful information being logged.

Comment: I did enable logging. I see the the looping call keeps running all the time with out any problem as a task. So this task is never ending.. From the logs I see that when ever I request the http url, I see responses. But suddenly, it stops receiving the requests, when ever I fire them and I get no response. (page cannot be found). Even after this the loopingCall keeps running.